# Some languages aren't processed / displayed correctly in kivy! What's the deal with it?

Tags: python, text, unicode, kivy, rendering

I am writing a facts app, I want to support different languages in my app, and I already have the code for that, but what doesn't work is some languages like Arabic and Japanese. When I put the text into a string inside the app this is what kivy renders:

[image: example]

I tried to use arabic reshaper or unicode with unicode parser (my version of config parser) nothing worked.

Any advice?
Thanks!

Comment: You will probably need to use specific fonts that support specific languages and probably package those fonts with your app. Then switch fonts for your `Labels` when you switch languages.

Comment: Hi, @Yaros, did you find a solution? In a similar problem, the LabelBase.register method (I believe the method John mentioned), with an addition of an .otf (font) file solved the issue for me, except for MDToolbar. Does your app also changes the title in the MDToolbar? Have you find a solution for MDToolbar?